# WPF bind the foreground colour of a listviewitem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, listviewitem

How would i bind the foreground colour of a ListViewItem to a property of a model?

```
public class UserModel : BaseModel
{
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public int UserID { get; private set; }
    public Brush Colour
    {
        get
        {
            return m_colour;
        }
        set
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(m_colour, value))
                return;

            m_colour = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Colour");
        }
    }

    private Brush m_colour = Brushes.Black;

    public UserModel(int userID, string userName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        UserID = userID;
    }
}
```

`<ListView Name="lvClients" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,5,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="UserName" />`

Comment: Asking something in question form, and posting your own answer is perfectly acceptable.  But please do it right.  Actually ask the question, and actually answer it.

Comment: Might just be me, but I see a question and no answer... ?

Answer (score 2):

How you find your color property depends on your full structure:

```
<ListView Name="lvClients" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,5,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="UserName">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=Color}"/>   
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Or you just bind to the `Foreground` of the `ListView` directly which will cause the items to have the same foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `ItemTemplate`. For instance

```
<Window.Resources>

<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
  <StackPanel Background={Binding Colour}>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UserName}" />
  </StackPanel>  
</DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"/>
```

More info on this can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx